# Pip succeeds but ImportError with Pandas - even inside virtualenv

Tags: python, pip

I believe I'm following commonly perscribed means of installing a python package. First I activate the virtual environment:

```
[]$ source virt_env/bin/activate
```

Then I check to see that the python and pip versions and locations are correct:

```
(virt_env) []$ which python
~/virt_env/bin/python
(virt_env) []]$ which pip
~/virt_env/bin/pip
```

Now I attempt to install with pip and it succeeds

```
(virt_env) []$ pip install pandas
Collecting pandas
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b7/e3/f52d484244105fa3d558ce8217a5190cd3d40536076bef66d92d01566325/pandas-0.23.4-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting numpy>=1.9.0 (from pandas)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9e/eb/c9eda9f4865d669e0bb37ce5c780e86c63daa54ca827b95a171429012d08/numpy-1.15.3-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.5.0 in ./virt_env/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from pandas) (2.7.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2011k in ./virt_env/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from pandas) (2018.5)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in ./virt_env/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.5.0->pandas) (1.11.0)
Installing collected packages: numpy, pandas
Successfully installed numpy-1.15.3 pandas-0.23.4
```

However, when I try to import it in my python session, I cannot find pandas

```
(virt_env) []$ python
Python 2.7.14 (default, May  2 2018, 18:31:34)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pandas
```

Is this not the correct way to install? Looking in `./virt_env/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` I see that pandas is no where to be found. Am I doing anything wrong?

I have tried doing `python -m pip install pandas` as well with no success.

I am on an Amazon ec2 instance running Amazon Linux.

**Edit:** `python -m site` returns the following:

```
sys.path = [
    '',
    '/home/myuser/virt_env/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
    '/home/myuser/virt_env/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
    '/home/myuser/virt_env/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
    '/home/myuser/virt_env/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages',
    '/home/myuser/virt_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
    '/home/myuser/virt_env/lib64/python2.7',
    '/home/myuser/virt_env/lib/python2.7',
    '/home/myuser/virt_env/lib64/python2.7/site-packages',
    '/home/myuser/virt_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
    '/home/myuser/virt_env/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload',
    '/usr/lib64/python2.7',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7',
]
USER_BASE: '/home/myuser/.local' (doesn't exist)
USER_SITE: '/home/muser/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages' (doesn't exist)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: False
```

I am also able to install things if I use

```
pip install --install-option="--prefix=/home/myuser/virt_env" pandas
```

and then move the resulting files to the correct location.

Comment: Since `pip` reports the packages to be installed, it should be able list them. What does `pip show -f pandas` return?

Comment: blank. I think this has to do with pip not installing packages to the right location, but I don't know where that location is.

Comment: Hmm, can you then check what location `pip` itself is installed (`pip -V` prints that) and also, what does `python -m site` return when run inside the `virt_env`?

Comment: If `pip` itself is ok, then it must be some fiddling in `sys.path` happening somewhere.

Comment: @hoefling I've edited the question to show the result of `python -m site`. I do think there's something wrong with the installation path because I'm able to get correct installation if I use the `--prefix` option and move the resulting files into `dist-packages`.

Comment: @hoefling I'm starting to suspect this is due to me using an old version of `virtualenv`: 15.1.0 - do you think that could be the source of the problem?

Comment: I don't think there's an issue with `virtualenv` version, I'm using 15.1.0 on lots of CentOS machines without any problem. However, I'm not sure whether your Python environment is ok - if I spin an `amazonlinux` container, install `python-virtualenv` and create a fresh virtual env, I get the correct site output and am able to install packages from the start, including `pandas` or `numpy`, to `$VIRTUAL_ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages`.

Comment: I'm not quite sure where you should start looking without knowing what changes were made to the python env, but it is definitely worth checking whether `PYTHONPATH` is set, a handmade `sitecustomize.py` is sitting somewhere in the site packages, or some unwanted packages are installed either in system or user site packages.

Comment: @hoefling for some reason, this was fixed by simply reinstalling virtualenv to 16.0.0